# Sharing variables in fragment shader GLSL

Tags: fragment, glsl

I have tried this fragment shader.

But the result is unexpected.

```
void main() {
    float test;
    if(gl_FragCoord.x == 300.0) {
        test = 1.0;
    }

    gl_FragColor = vec4(test, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

This program makes all fragments white colored.
But it's unexpected because shaders run asynchronously for each fragment.

Note that the colour is dependent to value of test in the *if* block. For example, if I change it to 0 it will fill all frags with lightblue.

I had expected it to just fill fragments with x=300.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code exhibits undefined behavior, since you never initialize `test`.

Furthermore, even if you did, the condition itself will almost certainly never be fulfilled. `gl_FragCoord` is not required to be an integer, so you're doing floating-point equality. The system is not required to provide exact values, so such equality tests will almost certainly fail.